# Do you know how to parse string which are wrapped in a keywords?

Tags: php, gettext, poedit

I'm trying to parse an application with Poedit.
Most of my translation use a translate() method but in some views file (.phtml) I use a special keyword such as My string

Do you know could I specify to poedit ?

Thank you

Edit:

I know how to add keyword such translate, setLabel, etc... but they are all methods.
I need to add something like %s and poedit will know that the string to translate is %s which wrapped around  tag element

Answer (score 0):

After opening a *.po file, got Catalog > Settings > Keywords to add your keyword.

[alt text http://img828.imageshack.us/img828/1479/65430288.png](http://img828.imageshack.us/img828/1479/65430288.png)